# Changing the position of navigationItem titleView to left side

Tags: ios, iphone

I need something like "< Delivery" an arrow which is a back button with a label at its side to left but instead of this I'm getting something like "<           Delivery"

I have searched a lot but didn't get anything useful that worked. let me show you the code up till now.

```
// setting up background image of backbutton
UIButton *backBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *backBtnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gallery--arrow.png"]  ;
[backBtn setBackgroundImage:backBtnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(goback) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
backBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,8,15);
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backBtn] ;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
// ends 


// text beside back button in header
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,150,30)];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GoodMobiPro-CondBold" size:24];
label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
label.text = selectedArea;
[label sizeToFit];
```

please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why cant you use like as follows?

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,150,30)];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GoodMobiPro-CondBold" size:24];
label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:label] ;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

Comment: I tried your code. My label came on left side but my back button disappeared. May be because you put label on leftBarButtonItem whereas my back button is also is in leftBarButtonItem

Comment: self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:btn1,btn2,nil]; issue resolved thanks

Comment: be aware that you're blowing away your interactive pop gesture recognizer (swipe back) when you use a custom left bar item like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
//back button first
UIButton *backBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *backBtnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gallery--arrow.png"]  ;
[backBtn setBackgroundImage:backBtnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(goback) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
backBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,8,15);
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backBtn] ;

//then label 

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
label.text = @"<";
// other properties , fonts , background etc
[label sizeToFit];

UIBarButtonItem *leftLabelBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:label target:yourTarget selector:yourSelector];

Now set self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = @[backButton,leftLabelBarButton];
```

> Previous Explanation

You need to use `[UIBarButton alloc] initWithCustomView:` where you pass your own `UILabel` as custom View

and then set

`self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = @[customViewBarButton,imageBarButton];`

That way you can have label and image on the left side of the navigation bar

Comment: Can you elaborate your point via code? it will help me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below method and let me know the result.

```
UIView * customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 30.0)];

customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIButton * customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[customButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

customButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100.0, 30.0);

[customButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[customView addSubview:customButton];

UILabel * customLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(customButton.frame.origin.x + customButton.frame.size.width, customButton.frame.origin.y, 200.0, 30.0)];

customLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

customLabel.text = @"Your title";

[customView addSubview:customLabel];

UIBarButtonItem * leftItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customView];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftItem;

leftItem = nil;
```

Thanks!